# Enable search filter in act_windows

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I know that we can enable the search filter like this

```
<field name="context">{'search_default_Product':1}</field>
```

But what if I want to programmatically enable the filter? Where can I put the code to enable it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your full requirement? An idea is to use a server action on the menu item, which can call a method returning an action. That would be a way to dynamically set the context, but has its disadvantages, too.

Comment: Before opening the tree view I need to check if the current user is one of the selected user (I put this value inside many2many field res.config_settings). If true I need to disable the filter otherwise, enable the filter.

Comment: That should work with my idea.

Comment: Can you give example of how a server action on the menu item can call a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your menu item's action to a server action. Any action can be referenced in menu items.

The server action (`ir.actions.server`) should reference the model which should be opened by the menu. And now you have some options. Three of them are hopefully easy to understand:

1. Use type `code` in the server action and call a model method. The method should return a window action in form of a dictionary. The code would look like:

```py
action = model.my_model_method_returning_an_action()
```

2. Use type `code` in the server action and create your action on-the-fly. The code would look like:

```py
action = {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'tree,form',
    'res_model': 'my.model',
    'target': 'current',
}
if env.user in env['res.config_settings'].check_my_m2m():
    action['context'] = {'search_default_Product': 1}
```

3. Use type `code` in the server action and call a prepared window action, but manipulate the context:

```py
action = env.ref('my.external.id.of.the.action.to.call').read()[0]
if env.user in env['res.config_settings'].check_my_m2m():
    if 'context' in action:
        action['context'].update({'search_default_Product': 1})
    else:
        action['context'] = {'search_default_Product': 1}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this. This makes odoo much more flexible. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this in ir.actions.act_window so that it can enable the filter automatically.